# QWebEngineView static release

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebengine

When i try to add QT += webenginewidgets in .PRO its show this error:

```
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webenginewidgets
```

Qt already compiled for static release,

what i need is relesing my application (static build)

which have QtQWebEngineView to display some web sites,

I use QT 5.6.0 msvc 2013.

```
view = new QWebEngineView(this);
view->load(QUrl("https://www.google.com"));
view->resize(500, 800);
view->show();
```